# Looking for the best provider

Tags: web3-providers

What’s the best multi-chain provider? I want to use Polygon, Avalanche, Solana, & Ethereum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am biased as I work with QuickNode; QuickNode is a leading multi-chain blockchain provider with 23+ chains. It has been the fastest and most performant provider in the space for quite some time now. With a global network of nodes, it gives the lowest latency and has robust, reliable infrastructure.

Blogposts on deep research comparing different providers:

1. https://blog.quicknode.com/quicknode-the-quickest-solana-node-provider/
2. https://blog.quicknode.com/justifying-quick-in-quicknode-response-time-comparison-of-various-blockchain-node-providers/

Check out all supported chains here: https://www.quicknode.com/chains

Answer (score 3):

I'm with Chainstack. Check it out, we have Polygon, Avalanche, Solana, Ethereum and much more, see [all the protocols](https://chainstack.com/protocols/). We are always multi-chain and tons of other features on top like load-balancing, subgraphs, ipfs etc.

3 million monthly requests on the free plan too.